# django: is there a black magic on extra fields on many-to-many relationships?

Tags: python, django, many-to-many

It's from Django's official doc: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships

The models are like:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='Membership')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Membership(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    date_joined = models.DateField()
    invite_reason = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

In the end, it gives such an example:

```
# Find all the members of the Beatles that joined after 1 Jan 1961
>>> Person.objects.filter(
...     group__name='The Beatles',
...     membership__date_joined__gt=date(1961,1,1))
[<Person: Ringo Starr]
```

My question is how Person model is aware of a group and membership attributes since they are not defined on it. Is it just a magic of manytomany with through or it's some kind of universal one in Django?

If I were to achieve the same query, I would think following code more natural (from Django's orm perspective, not from business one):

```
Membership.objects.filter(group__name='The Beatles', date_joined__gt=date(1961,1,1))).select_related('person')
```

**Edit**
I read the document again and do find such backwards is universal. In paragraph https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships, it mentions:

> It works backwards, too. To refer to a "reverse" relationship, just
>   use the lowercase name of the model.

I've never used this backwards query before. So the first time I saw it, it banged my brain. Sorry that this thread turns out to be stupid. But I hope it helps people who skip the very (thin) line in that paragraph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not a magic of ManyToMany fields; its a universal one of the django ORM with foreign key (including ManyToMany) relations.

E.g., if you have

```
class Musician(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    band = models.ForeignKey("Band")

class Band(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

You can do something like `Musician.objects.filter(band__name='The Beatles')`  The query can be seen with django-debug-toolbar or from the django shell with:

```
from django.db import connection
connection.queries
```

and will be comrpised of a complicated JOIN statement.  The SQL query constructed by the ORM will look something like:

```
SELECT "appname_musician"."id", "appname_musician"."name", "appname_musician"."band_id" 
    FROM "appname_musician" 
    INNER JOIN "appname_band" ON ("appname_musician"."band_id" = "appname_band"."id") 
    WHERE "appname_band"."name" = "The Beatles";
```

---

EDIT:
If you did  `Band.objects.filter(musician__name = 'Ringo Starr')` the ORM would translate it into:

```
SELECT "appname_band"."id", "appname_band"."name", "appname_band"."genre"
    FROM "appname_band" 
    INNER JOIN "appname_musician" ON ("appname_musician"."band_id" = "appname_band"."id") 
    WHERE "appname_musician"."name" = "Ringo Starr";
```

The ORM knows the relationships and can convert your ORM query into the appropriate SQL.  It doesn't matter that Band doesn't have a musician object; you were able to give django a clear request:
I want all band objects, where there's musician linked to the band with the name 'Ringo Starr'.

I think you may be hung up on thinking about object encapsulation (e.g., band doesn't have a musician; how can you filter based upon it)?  Its not black magic, as the filter request is clear and unambiguous -- and takes as arguments not members of the Band object; but commands to filter by.  E.g., you could do `Band.objects(name__icontains = "The")`, even though there's no `name__icontains` object in Band.  The ORM converts your request into SQL, which is simple to execute quickly.

---

EDIT2:
Your final example:

```
class Musician(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    initial_band = models.ForeignKey("Band", related_name = 'initial_band_members')
    final_band = models.ForeignKey("Band", related_name = 'final_band_members')

class Band(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=50)

try: ## create some objects
    cream,_ = Band.objects.get_or_create(name="Cream", genre="Classic Rock")
    derek, _ = Band.objects.get_or_create(name="Derek and the Dominos", genre="Classic Rock")
    beatles, _ = Band.objects.get_or_create(name="The Beatles", genre="Classic Rock")
    wings, _ = Band.objects.get_or_create(name="Wings", genre="Classic Rock")
    Musician.objects.get_or_create(name="Eric Clapton", initial_band=cream, final_band=derek)
    Musician.objects.get_or_create(name="Paul McCartney", initial_band=beatles, final_band=wings)
    Musician.objects.get_or_create(name="John Lennon", initial_band=beatles, final_band=beatles)

except:
    pass
```

Then queries like `Band.objects.filter(musician__name='Paul McCartney')` don't work (`FieldError`), but queries like 
`Band.objects.filter(initial_band_members__name='Paul McCartney')` will give back The Beatles found with the following SQL (using sqlite as a db; the command is dependent on the DB backend):

```
SELECT "testing_band"."id", "testing_band"."name", "testing_band"."genre" 
  FROM "testing_band" 
  INNER JOIN "testing_musician" ON ("testing_band"."id" = "testing_musician"."final_band_id") 
  WHERE "testing_musician"."name" = Paul McCartney '
```

Comment: I can totally understand your example since band is a foreign key defined on Musician model. But in my question, Person model doesn't have person attribute defined. To answer my question, please tell me how it's possible to do the reverse thing like Band.objects.filter(musician__name = 'Ringo Starr').

Comment: It's the same essential mechanism.  The django ORM translates your django query into SQL.  I'll edit with an example.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I read the document again and realised that the reverse query is possible. But it's a one-line thing. So I guess my eyes just skipped it before.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps look into https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/ for your answer. In general joins are used.

Comment: This article can't answer my question. In my question, Person model isn't aware of group or membership attribute. I know django will add group_set and membership_set managers to it. But group & membership attributes? No django doc ever mention the possibility of that.